# Transforming ordinal logistic regression coefficients to beta weights

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients

Ordinal logistic regression analysis result in coefficients which are log odds, and not b or beta weights, like in a linear regression. For example:

[image]

1. How can I compare the log odds of the DVs? Is it correct to say that DV1 effect on the IV is 11%, compared to DV2 (-0.071/-0.619)?
2. Is there any way to convert the log odds to beta weights?

Comment: Just as a sidenote OLS refers to Ordinary Least Square. Not to Ordinal Logistic (Regression)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Comment: I am a bit confused w.r.t. your choice of abbreviations: If DV abbreviates "dependent variable", you talk about the effect that the dependent variable DV1 has on the independent variable IV?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections to the title and table

Answer (score 1):

In logistic regression you linearly regress the log odds, so the fitted coefficients are the "beta weights" for the log odds. So you can say that the "IV1 effect on the **log odds** of the DV is 11%, compared to IV2".

Now, the "log odds"-function (or "logit") is nonlinear, and thus is its inverse, the logistic sigmoid function $\sigma$. Thus, the effect on the DV, of a unit change in an IV, is not constant but depends on the value of the IV.

So, if you want to know the effect of a change in the IV $\mathbf x$ on the DV $y$ at the point $\mathbf x= \mathbf{x_0}$, you could compute the gradient of $\sigma(\beta\cdot\mathbf x)$ at $\mathbf{x_0}$, which gives you the linear approximation of the effects of all your scalar IVs at this particular value $\mathbf{x_0}$. Recall, that, if you have $k$ IVs, then $\mathbf x \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, because an extra dimension is added for the intercept.

Comment: Thanks Frank. The issue is that I need a general solution, i.e., a formula that I can automate.